# How do I keep track of websocket id's and send to a specific Websocket from ashx webserver in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, websocket, ashx

I have a working echowebsocket server built in an ashx page using vb.net. it uses Websocket.SendAsync to push the message down to the client.

I need to be able to push a message to a specific websocket connection.

in a card game,

- Player 1 and player two both connect to the server
- When Player 1 takes his turn I need the server to push down a message to player 2 with player one's move in text.

so I need the server to keep track of who is connected and who to send the message too.